# How do I prove that $|Z|=5$?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I have the following problem:

> Let $S_1,S_2$ be two distinct $5$-sylow subgroups of $G$.${}^\dagger$ We want to show that $S_1\cap S_2=\{1\}$. We argue by contradiction and assume that $Z=S_1\cap S_2$, different from $\{1\}$. First show that $|Z|=5$

I don't see it how we should get $5$ because since they are distinct $|S_1\cap S_2|=0$ in my opinion. Where is the mistake?

---

$\dagger$: See the comments: $|G|=400$.

Comment: Use Lagrange's theorem. Also, the intersection of two subgroups can never be empty since they both contain the identity.

Comment: So can I say that since the intersection of two subgroups is again a subgroup we know by lagrange that $|Z| \,\,| \,\,|G|$ but we also know that $|G|=400=5^2\cdot 16$ but then here I would have a lot of possibilities?

Comment: You seem to be confusing "distinct" with "disjoint". Distinct subgroups doesn't mean they have no elements in common. It just means that they are not _the same_ subgroup.

Comment: $H=|S_1\cap S_2| $ is a subgroup of both $S_i$.  But that means that the possible orders of $H$ are $1,5,25$.  If it were $25$ then $S_1=S_2$.

Comment: I don't see how you reached the conclusion in your last sentence, @lulu

Comment: The $5-$Sylow subgroups have order $25$.  More broadly, if $p^n$ exactly divides $|G|$ then the $p-$Sylow subgroups of $G$ have order $p^n$

Comment: and what do we do with the case $1$?

Comment: Oh, thank you, @lulu. Of course! I didn't read Wave's comment.

Comment: We have assumed that not to be the case, @Wave.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|S_1|=25=|S_2|$, we can count the number of elements in the *subset* $S_1S_2$ of $G$ as follows.
$$|S_1S_2|=\frac{|S_1| \cdot |S_2|}{|S_1 \cap S_2|}=\frac{25 \cdot 25}{|S_1 \cap S_2|} \leq |G|=400$$
So $|S_1 \cap S_2| \geq \frac{625}{400} \gt 1$. By Lagrange's Theorem $|S_1 \cap S_2 | \mid |S_1|=25$. Since $S_1$ and $S_2$ are distinct, $|S_1 \cap S_2| \neq 25$. Hence $|S_1 \cap S_2| =5$.